# this.Visible() won't work on Ecipse contrary Netbeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, this, visibility

I'm usung now Eclipse to develop a Java application.
My problem is when I pass from interface I1 to interface I2.
I want to hide I1 and show I2 when I click a button in I2.

I tried to use this instruction in NetBeans:

```
I2 interface = new I2();
this.setVisible(false);
interface.setVisible(true);
```

But trying this in Eclipse ann error occur, Eclipse ask me to create a mrthod 'setVisible' .. Now I use eclipse ...

[image]

Why ?? and what can I do??
Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two pieces of code are not the same. In the Eclipse example `this` refers to the anonymous inner class of type `ActionListener` which I assume doesn't have a `setVisible` method. I guess you're trying to call the setVisible method of the parent class, try removing `this`, then it should automatically refer to the parent class' method, like so:

```
ws.setVisible(true);
setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first snapshot is for the project that I work on and the second is for an old project.
Thanks for replying! It worked finally... :)

I confirm:
`setVisible(false);` for Eclipse and `this.setVisible(false);` for NetBeans.

Comment: Glad it worked! I don't think it's a difference in editors though. NetBeans should also give you an error for the new code, because `this` refers to the anonymous inner type, not the parent class.